# DD-WRT Android USB Tether

Tags: usb, dd-wrt, tethering

I have an older WNDR4500 router that has BS DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/22/14) - build 25697 installed.

The router has 2 USB ports, and I was wondering if I could USB tether with my Android phone to the router for an internet connection. If possible, how do I do it?

Currently, I go from my android phone to a laptop via PDANet, then to my router via ethernet, then to the rest of my network. I would like to remove the laptop from the equation if possible.

Comment: I am trying to do the same with an 08/23/2015 "kong" build of dd-wrt on a Netgear R7000 router. It should work, but I cannot seem to get it working. See more here. DD-WRT Forum :: View topic - 4G USB Modem
http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=981336#981336
"I can recommend Kong Mod to achieve this. Works right out of the box, at least for me. The only thing I did was to plug in the dongle, select '3G/4G' as Wan connection and filled in the APN. Everything worked directly, no additional modules to load. Success or failure is of course dependent on the dongle being supported."

Comment: Wow. I forgot that I asked this.. I finally gave up and used a spare laptop as a bridge between my cell phone and router.

Comment: I initiallly did it with a laptop as a bridge as well. But after posting my comment, I finally got this working with dd-wrt too. I like not having to use a laptop as a bridge.

Comment: I dislike using the laptop as well. But I think I came to the conclusion that since I'm on vzw grandfathered unlimited data and I was not able to get the tethering add-on I don't think it'll work for me. But thanks for the link!

Comment: If it works with the laptop, it can work with dd-wrt.